# Reduce boilerplate from __init__ using Inheritance

Tags: python, python-internals

I am trying to inject constructor i.e. `__init__` via super class, to avoid boilerplate code in `__init__` in all my domain classes.

For example:

```
class Structure:
    _fields = []

    def __init__(self, *args):
        if len(args) != len(self._fields):
            raise TypeError("Wrong # arguments")
        for name, value in zip(self._fields, args):
            setattr(self, name, value)

class Stock(Structure):
    _fields = ['name', 'shares', 'price']

stock = Stock("Amzn", "11", "2100")
print(stock.name)
```

The code above works fine when the constructor is limited to `*args`. But there are some domain classes that takes `**kwargs` too.

For example something like below:

```
class Structure:
    _fields = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if (len(args) + len(kwargs)) != len(self._fields):
            raise TypeError("Wrong # arguments")

        for name, value in zip(self._fields, args):
            setattr(self, name, value)

class Stock(Structure):
    _fields = ['name', 'shares', 'price']

stock = Stock("Amzn", "11", price = "2100")
stock.price #AttributeError, stock object has no attribute 'price'
```

But obviously the code above won't set the kwargs, because I never touched kwargs in `__init__`. Any idea how can I get this fixed?

Comment: something like the one-line constructor might be what you're looking for? see the bottom of this webpage: http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/one_liners.html

Comment: I'd likely throw my monitor at whoever wrote that code if it was anything I was responsible for ;) Sure, it may save a tiny bit of boilerplate, but as it's not standard convention, you'll run into all kinds of issues if you ever want to rely on Python's tooling. For example, what you're trying to do renders help() completely useless. You can't assign type hints (if you chose to do so). etc etc

Comment: @DemianBrecht, while your comment has some point. I have seen some codes that use similar tricks to define classes and types on run time. Sure there are also other ways to do that in Python, but in all these cases you don't need help and "standard" tooling.

Comment: Specifically when you are writing frameworks or libraries. You can find such things happening in Django, Flask etc too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about checking if `kwargs` exists?

```
>>> class SC: 
...:     _fields = [] 
...:     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...:         if (len(args) + len(kwargs)) != len(self._fields):
...:              raise TypeError("Wrong # arguments") 
...:         for name, value in zip(self._fields, args): 
...:             setattr(self, name, value) 
...:         if kwargs: 
...:             self.__dict__.update(kwargs) 
...:                                                                                                                                                                                      

>>> class SD2(SC): 
...     _fields = ['name', 'shares', 'price'] 


>>> i = SD2(name='Amzn', shares=1, price=2)                                                                                                                                              
>>> i.name                                                                                                                                                                               
'Amzn'
>>> i.shares  
1
```

This works like this too:

```
>>>u= SD2('Amzn', shares=1, price=2)                                                                                                                                                             
>>>u.name                                                                                                                                                                                
'Amzn'
```

Comment: `kwargs` will always "exist"; the code simply checks whether it is empty. This check is not necessary; `self.__dict__.update({})` correctly has no effect.